# How to run a method before some special methods?

Tags: java, spring, aop

In my business, I have to execute a method (imagine an access controll-like method) before some special methods(e.g. save, update,etc) to check some prerequisites and then execute the intended method. It is obvious that the most simple way is to call that controlling method at the very beginning lines of those methods, but I'm looking for something like @Before. something clean.
Any answer/hints will be appreciated.

Comment: You tagged the answer.. What's wrong with AspectJ `@Before`?

Comment: Hint: you *know* that the answer is related to AOP. So just read the documentation about it, and try something: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Comment: @Before is only for JUnit and aside from this, it runs before every test case, not few of them. I want something during application running, not test scope.

Comment: @Khodabakhsh No, it's a different annotation, has nothing to do with JUnit. Go through the link provided above.

Comment: @MarounMaroun you know, I want something like @Before({"save","edit"})

Comment: @Khodabakhsh Please read the tutorial, it covers all what you need to know.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Thank you, certainly I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Spring AOP + AspectJ**

---

In simple, Spring AOP + AspectJ allow you to intercept method easily.

> Common AspectJ annotations :
>
> @Before – Run before the method execution @After – Run after the
>   method returned a result @AfterReturning – Run after the method
>   returned a result, intercept the returned result as well.
>   @AfterThrowing – Run after the method throws an exception @Around –
>   Run around the method execution, combine all three advices above.

**Steps**

---

***1. First you should enable AspectJ***

To enable AspectJ, you need aspectjrt.jar, aspectjweaver.jar and spring-aop.jar. See following Maven pom.xml file.

```
<!-- Spring AOP + AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

***2. Enable AspectJ***

In your context config file add

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

***3. After that use AspectJ @Before***

In below example, the method1() method will be executed before the execution of  method2() method.

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    @Before("execution(* your.package.method2(..))")
    public void method1(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        System.out.println("method1() is running!");
        System.out.println(" ----  " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        System.out.println("******");
    }

}
```